# Django template filter - one line

Tags: javascript, django, templates, filter

I'm looking for a Django template filter that turns a multi-line construction into one big line. Has anyone implemented it?
The reason is - I have a form, {{form.as_p}} creates a multi-line html fragment, I want to create a javascript variable which is an html fragment, but when I do like this:

```
var new_div_text = '{{form.as_p}}';
```

it doesn't work. The reason is obvious, in javascript constructions like

```
var hello = 'Hello
world';
```

are invalid!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reading your use case, it doesn't appear that you just want to remove lines. What if one of your form labels contains a ' character? Oops, your javascript is now invalid.
Django comes with a filter called *[escapejs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#escapejs)* which us used for precisely this problem.

With escapejs, you would type:

```
var newDivText = '{{ form.as_p|escapejs }}'
```

and you won't have to worry about any characters destroying your javascript.

Comment: Exactly! I didn't think about single-quote escaping, because as_p uses double-quotes, not single-quotes, but as I see now, escapejs is really what I need!