# Jquery append issuse

Tags: jquery, django

I'm trying this:

```
$form = ('<form>');
{% for field in fields %}
    $.form.append({{field}});
{% endfor %}
```

This working for all fields but not works for textarea.
I saw source code of page and looks like this:

```
$fieldset.append('<textarea cols="40" id="id_tekst_area" rows="10">
</textarea>');
```

The `</textarea>` is on new line. Why? I thing this is reason why not working.

Comment: You have an XSS vulnerability.  You need to escape your strings.

Comment: Anny suggestions how? What is the best way?

Comment: I'm googling but nothing for now :). Help please :)

Comment: What are you trying to implement here ? Please be clear.

Comment: I'm trying to programmatically create form from django model fields..

Comment: See the post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717683/django-template-filter-one-line). I think this is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **escapejs** filter.
See the same question asked here: [Django template filter - one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717683/django-template-filter-one-line)

```
$form = ('<form>');
{% for field in fields %}
    $.form.append({{field|escapejs}});
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! You have a bear :D